# изменить надпись личный кабинет ocstore

Tags: php, ocstore

Всем привет!) У меня установлен ocStore 2.3.0.2.3.
Я хочу, чтобы, когда клиент авторизовался, было написан его ник, а не "личный кабинет". Очень долго уже ищу, не могу найти. Нашел вот такую строку, но куда ее вставлять не знаю:
$data['text_username'] = $this->customer->getFirstName();

Спасибо за любую помощь!)

Answer (score 1):

- На сайте - правой мышей на том месте, где хотите выводить ник юзера;
- Смотрите стрктуру `html` в этом месте, находите эту струкуру в `.tpl` файле в `admin/view/template/`. Cкорее всего это будет `admin/view/template/common/header.tpl`, точно не скажу, не помню;
- Смотрите, какая переменная (элемент массива $data) выводиться в этом месте;
- Находите контроллер данной вьюхи;
- В контроллере находите где и как эта переменная (элемент массива $data) попадает в массив $data;
- Делаете замену;

Comment: Спасибо большое!